# Can I use an anchor link inside a form element?

Tags: html, forms, tags, anchor

I have a website with an anchor tag at the bottom I want to jump to from the top.  But I want to put the jump link inside a form element.

```
<form name=sortby onClick='submit()' method='get'>
  <div>
    <input type=radio name=sortby value=name onClick='submit()'>
    Sort By Name
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href='#bottom'>There are 587 entries on this page</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type=radio name=sortby value=date onClick='submit()'>
    Sort By Date
  </div>
  <input type=hidden name=artist value=''>
</form>
<a id='bottom' href='#top'>Back to the top</a>
```

I have done a test where I place the anchor link outside the form code and it works.  Is there some no-no about putting it within the  element?

What I'm experiencing is that the page jumps to the bottom and immediately back to the top using each of Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer browsers in windows 7.  Note that in Firefox, there is a delay before it jumps to the top as if the browser is processing something.

Answer (score 0):

The link itself won't do anything to affect the form functionality, if that's the question. This is more or less a case of semantics. It's not a great practice but it's also not going to break anything.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the window jumps back to the top of the page after jumping to the bottom?  BTW, it only does this if the link is within the <form> element.

Comment: Do you have an anchor on the page for #top? <a name="top"></a>?

Comment: When I try your fiddle, I get the error "{"error": "Please use POST request"}".  I don't have a #top in my page because #top is a global tag that automatically means the top of the page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by global tag. #top is not a global attribute in HTML. You would want to add an anchor for top. Generally linking to anything with the target of just # is going to jump you up thought.

Comment: Try it.  adding an anchor to #top WILL take you to the top of the page without any destinations in the code.  All modern browsers today understand #top, so even if your id or <a name="top"></a> anchor is not in your page, it will still return you to the top of the page. However, all other anchors need to be defined in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem...  The top line should be changed to this:

```
<form method='get'>
```

Getting rid of the onClick='submit()' was the key.  Basically clicking anywhere in the form element submitted the form.  It never let me actually click the link which was "behind/under" the form element.